# No suitable conversion from to * exist

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new to C++ and I have no idea why I can't send parking as a parameter. It's the first time I use struct, so maybe I'm forgetting something. I've tried sending the adress to parking but I get an error.

```
const int MAX_TAB = 10;

struct bike
{
    int Number;
    string Type;
};
bike ReadFile(bike parking[]);
int void main()
{
    bike parking[MAX_TAB];
    ReadFile(parking[MAX_TAB]); // This line is incorrect
}

bike ReadFile(bike parking[])
{
...
return parking[MAX_TAB];

}
```

Why does this not work? And how can I make it works? 
Thanks you

Comment: The function `ReadFile` takes in an array, however, you are passing in a single element of type `bike`.

Comment: Note that `void main` is not valid C++. The only acceptable declarations of `main` are `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)` and while this isn't your issue here, you should definitely become accustomed to writing it like that

Comment: Consider replacing the C-style array with `std::array`, it prevents this kind of errors.

Comment: regarding: `int void main()`  This is not a valid signature for function: `main()`  Perhaps you meant: `int main( void )`

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: Please make up your mind as to which language you are using.  C and C++ are drastically different.

Comment: regarding: `bike parking[MAX_TAB];`  This does not compile!.  Suggest: `struct bike parking[MAX_TAB];`

Comment: regarding: `bike ReadFile(bike parking[]);`  This does not compile perhasp you meant: `struct bike ReadFile(bike parking[]);`

Comment: `string` is not a valid type name in C,  Perhaps you meant: `char type;` or `char * Type;`

Comment: regarding; `return parking[MAX_TAB];`  1) in C, an array offset has the range 0...(number of elements in array -1)  so `parking[ MAX_TAB ];  is actually reference one past the end of the array,  In general, this results in undefined behavior

Comment: in function: `ReadFile()` the last statement is trying to return an instance of the `struct bike`.  which agrees with the prototype and the signature of that function, BUT the call to that function, in main(), is ignoring the returned `struct bike`

Comment: in function: `main()`, this statement: `ReadFile(parking[MAX_TAB]);` should be: `struct bike myBike = ReadFile(parking);`

Comment: Note: in C, (not sure about C++)  a reference to the bare name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing arrays, don't add [].
Compiled using C++14 on [CPP.SH](http://cpp.sh/)

```
// dependecies
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

// namespace for string
using std::string;

// defined max tab for array
const int MAX_TAB = 50;

// structure definition 
struct bike
{
    int Number;
    string Type;
    string Test;
    int Km;
    int Stage;
};

// ReadFile(...) signature
bike ReadFile(bike *, size_t);

int main()
{
  bike parking[MAX_TAB]; //instantiate array of bike object
  ReadFile(parking, MAX_TAB);  //only pass the array itself, not the array[
}

// parameters are array* and size
bike ReadFile(bike parking[], size_t size)
{
    return *parking; //reference the array
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to return : Exception thrown at 0x7AF63030 (vcruntime140d.dll) in project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x008F3FB8.

Comment: @LaVague, change the return type here to pointer, 
`// parameters are array* and size
bike ReadFile(bike parking[], size_t size)
{
    return *parking; //reference the array
}`

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= MAX_TAB; i++)` is an off by 1 error. It should be `for (i = 0; i < MAX_TAB; i++)` or better yet actually use the size parameter `for (i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea why I can't send parking as a parameter.

You can't do this because parking array decays to pointer, and it doesn't take the size of the array.

```
ReadFile(parking[MAX_TAB]);  // MAX_TAB is not taken as input param
```

Instead you should do this:

```
bike ReadFile(bike parking[], size_t size);
```

and to call that function:

```
ReadFile(parking, MAX_TAB);
```

Comment: When I call `bike ReadFile(bike parking[], size_t size);` , it says that `parking[]` expected an expression, which is why I was including MAX_TAB as input parameter. I still get this error.

Comment: @LaVague that is a function declaration or prototype. When you call it you have to remove the array notation `[ ]`, ie `ReadFile(parking, MAX_TAB);`